# zeit-now v2 + apollo-server-express: playground error: Server cannot be reached

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql, vercel

Currently I am trying to get an api for my nextjs project to work.
For deployment I am using zeit's NOW v2 (locally via "now dev").

Everything works fine except the graphql-server.

In playground and via client I get an 404-error.
Queries are getting executed correctly, but I get an error-object(query results are in the response-field; 404).

Checking it in the playground-gui: same problem and in the playground-input field showing the message "Server cannot be reached".

Playground Initial Error:

```
{
  "error": "Response not successful: Received status code 404"
}
```

Playground after hello-query:

```
{
  "error": {
    "data": {
      "hello": "Hello world!"
    }
  }
}
```

Browser-Console Playground:

```
Error: "Response not successful: Received status code 404"
```

This is my graphql-server loaded with now:

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        hello: String
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => 'Hello world!',
    },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers,
                                    introspection: true, playground: true,
                                    subscriptions: {path: '/api'},
                                });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/api", cors: true });

module.exports = app;
```

Also tried [this](https://zeit.co/guides/deploying-apolloserver-to-now) example. Same problem.

Can anyone tell me how to get it running properly?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (server can't be reached). It was an authorization problem. The [GraphQL Playground docs](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground) mention the `request.credentials` setting:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    introspection: true,
    playground: {
      settings: {
        // So that auth works
        // Docs: https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground
        ['request.credentials']: 'same-origin',
      },
    },
    subscriptions: {path: '/api'}
});
```